# tkinter: How to have one labelframe under another expand as the page grows without leaving space between the two frames, using grid()

Tags: python, tkinter

I apologize in advance where I am new to tkinter. I am making a search tool to find a moniker(username) and am currently working on the front end. While working on this I have started using sticky to help the different parts stretch as the user adjusts the page size. My current problem is that as I stretch it downwards/south, a bunch of space is created between the first top and the bottom LabelFrame. What i want is for the bottom label frame to stretch out as the page is stretched by the user and not have it create that unwanted space.

I have used sticky nsew for the second frame so that it grows with the page without pulling away from the top labelframe. I would have the top label frame sticky to south but that would make the label frame grow as the page is stretched downward. Below is my code.

```
   def query_window(conn):
    window.destroy()
    q_window = Tk()
    q_window.title('Moniker Lookup')
    q_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    q_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    path = os.path.realpath(
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    icon = PhotoImage(file = path + "..\\assets\main_icon.png")
    q_window.iconphoto(False, icon)
    #q_window.geometry("700x700")

    #Create a search frame for the moniker search to sit in
    search_frame = tk.LabelFrame(q_window, text='Moniker Search')
    search_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    search_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    search_frame.grid(row = 0, column=0, pady=GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx=GLOBAL_PAD_X, sticky="nw")

    #Create a results frame for the treeview widget to sit in.
    output_frame = tk.LabelFrame(q_window, text='Results')
    output_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    output_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    output_frame.grid(row = 1, column=0, pady=GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx=GLOBAL_PAD_X, sticky="nsew")

    #Create area for user to provide Moniker
    moniker_label = tk.Label(search_frame, text="Moniker:")
    moniker_label.grid(row=0, column = 2, pady = GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx = GLOBAL_PAD_X)
    moniker_field = tk.Entry(search_frame)
    moniker_field.grid(row=0, column = 3, pady=GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx=GLOBAL_PAD_X, columnspan=2)

    #Create a run button
    run_button = tk.Button(search_frame, text="Run", command=lambda:
    moniker_query(moniker_field, conn, q_window), width=10)
    run_button.grid(row=0, column = 5, pady = GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx = GLOBAL_PAD_X)

    #Create a treeview to display output
    tv1 = ttk.Treeview(output_frame)
    tv1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    tv1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    #Create the tree scrolls
    tree_scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(output_frame, orient = "vertical", command=tv1.yview)
    tree_scroll_x = tk.Scrollbar(output_frame, orient="horizontal", command=tv1.xview)
    tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=tree_scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_y.set)
    tv1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady = GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx = GLOBAL_PAD_X, sticky="nsew")
    tree_scroll_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
    tree_scroll_x.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    tree_scroll_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S)
    tree_scroll_x.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Additionally, here is what my default page looks like on open and then when I have stretched the page.

[image: Default, on start.]

[image: When Stretched]

Comment: You have a nonzero `weight=` only for row 0 of your window - so that's where all excess space goes.  You want to apply weight to row 1, instead.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you mean @jasonharper

Comment: It means that you need to change  `q_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` to `q_window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a bit confused about `.rowconfigure`. When setting `weight=1`, resizing comes from the parent. I moved them closer to the widgets they affect. True, the size of the `Scrollbar` is a method of the `.grid_rowconfigure` itself. Here is a working sample.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

GLOBAL_PAD_Y = 10
GLOBAL_PAD_X = 10

q_window = Tk()
q_window.title('Moniker Lookup')
q_window.geometry("250x200")

# path = os.path.realpath(
#     os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
# icon = PhotoImage(file=path + "..\\assets\main_icon.png")
# q_window.iconphoto(False, icon)
#q_window.geometry("700x700")

# Create a search frame for the moniker search to sit in
q_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

search_frame = LabelFrame(q_window, text='Moniker Search')
search_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx=GLOBAL_PAD_X, sticky="new")

# Create a results frame for the treeview widget to sit in.
q_window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
q_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

output_frame = LabelFrame(q_window, text='Results')
output_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx=GLOBAL_PAD_X, sticky="nsew")

# Create area for user to provide Moniker
search_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
search_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
search_frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

moniker_label = Label(search_frame, text="Moniker:")
moniker_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx=GLOBAL_PAD_X, sticky='e')
moniker_field = Entry(search_frame)
moniker_field.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx=GLOBAL_PAD_X, sticky='we')


# Create a run button
run_button = Button(search_frame, text="Run", command=lambda: print("run"), width=10)
run_button.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx=GLOBAL_PAD_X, sticky='w')

# Create a treeview to display output
output_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
output_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

tv1 = ttk.Treeview(output_frame)
tv1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=GLOBAL_PAD_Y, padx=GLOBAL_PAD_X, sticky="nsew")

# Create the tree scrolls
tree_scroll_y = ttk.Scrollbar(output_frame, orient="vertical", command=tv1.yview)
tree_scroll_x = ttk.Scrollbar(output_frame, orient="horizontal", command=tv1.xview)
tree_scroll_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
tree_scroll_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
tree_scroll_y.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
tree_scroll_x.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=tree_scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_y.set)

q_window.mainloop()
```

I understand that you destroy the main application window and create a new one. It is better to use Toplevel for these purposes, and minimize or hide the main window, and destroy it only at the end of the program, since the main loop is associated with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the extra info! Since I am new to tkinter I am also new to the best practices. I appreciate you taking your time to give a solid answer here!